# C#: как убрать некоторые свойства базового класса из класса - наследника?

Tags: c#, ооп

У меня есть базовый класс, пусть это

```
class Person {
    internal string FirstName { get; set; }
    internal string LastName { get; set; }
    internal uint Age { get; set; }
}
```

А теперь я хочу странного. Ну, с этого же всегда всё начинается...

Я хочу, чтобы свойства FirstName и LastName перестали быть доступны как свойства в экземплярах класса - наследника. Например, я бы заменил их свойством FullName, которое состоит из их суммы, и эти два свойства стали мне не нужны.

Если я напишу:

```
class VipPerson : Person {
    internal string VipStatus { get; set; }
    internal string FullName {
        get { return base.FirstName + " " + base.LastName; }
    }
}
```

то после создания экземпляра `VipPerson vip = new VipPerson();` у переменной vip есть и FirstName, и LastName.

Применить в классе Person к этим двум полям модификатор sealed я не могу: я же ничего не override'чу.

Я пробовал объявить их в VipPerson и как private, и вот так вот

```
class VipPerson : Person {
    internal string VipStatus { get; set; }

    private new string FirstName { get; set; }
    private new string LastName { get; set; }

    internal string FullName {
        get { return base.FirstName + " " + base.LastName; }
    }
}
```

но при этом я просто получаю в vip доступ к полям класса Person. А сделать так, чтобы в vip их не было - я не могу.

Конечно, я могу сделать FirstName - LastName приватными в базовом классе, но тогда они не будут доступны в геттере свойства FullName.

Впечатление такое, что всё рассчитано на то, что класс может при наследовании только "разбухать", но никак не "ужиматься".

Не подскажет ли мне кто то из старших товарищей, имеющих больше опыта в C#/ООП, решение этой проблемы?

---

Господа, я поясню немного физический смысл, возможно, Вы сможете мне что то еще посоветовать.

Ко мне с сервера прилетает "короткая запись". В ней - грубо говоря, платеж в виде суммы, идентификатора валюты, и идетификатора контрагентов.

Потом я эту запись преобразую - в неё добавляются человеческие имена контрагентов, взятые из справочника, curId=1 превращается в USD и т.п.

Но по сути - это всё равно просто напросто запись.

И потом я набор таких записей "скармливаю" devexpress - гриду, который отлично умеет их показывать.

Но... все ID - шники при этом тоже остаются среди "доступных для показа" полей. И они, хоть и спрятаны , мозолят глаза. (то есть, находятся среди тех колонок, котрые можно выбрать и вывести на экран по специальной менюшке)

Я пытаюсь сделать "расширенный класс с человеческими названиями" используя наследование от "бедного класса с одними ID шниками", просто чтобы писать меньеш кода (некотрые ID шники то надо оставить, например, "цену" - цифра и есть цифра.

Comment: Это сделать нельзя, т.к. вы нарушите принцип ООП. Вы можете "перетереть" свойства, но чаще всего ваш класс никто не знает, а при доступе к вашему классу через родительский класс - свойства всёравно будут доступны в изначальном виде. Нектороые классы реализуют виртуальные методы, меняя которые можно повлиять на значение свойства. Если это имеется ввиду - то нужно делать свойство через виртуальный метод, или делать свойство виртуальным. Виртуальные существующие свойста - без проблем перетруться.

Comment: Можно скрыть свойство через приватность - но это тоже не всегда подходит.

Comment: Вопрос: если вы спрячете свойства `FirstName` и `LastName` в наследнике, то как планируете задавать их значения? В конструкторе? Тогда добавьте этот конструктор. И будем думать дальше.

Comment: Имхо, тут можно выделить интерфейс(ы): `IPerson` и/или `IVipPerson` с необходимыми свойствами. И реализовать эти интерфейсы у нужных классов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо большое за совет, я попробую перейти на интерфейсы. Еще - я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Возможно подойдет композиция, засунуть в `VipPerson` приватную ссылку на `Person`

Comment: @yolosora да, кстати, вариант без наследования - тоже вариант.

Comment: @nick_n_a - спасибо, да, с этой точки зрения я не смотрел... да, похоже, что это противоречит принципам ООП - ведь "даункастинг", или преобразование от потомка к базовому классу всегда должно работать.

Comment: Предлагаю вариант вообще без наследования, просто настройте маппер Person->VipPerson чтобы он работал так как вам надо

Comment: @S.H. а что если запилить кастомный атрибут, пометить им свойства, для которых не нужно генерить колонки, и просто в обработчике события генерации пропускать их, если найден атрибут?

Comment: Надо было сразу писать, в чем именно проблема, а не с велосипедами играться. :) Интерфейсы вам не помогут, потому что генератор колонок той же DataGrid не смотрит в тип контейнера, он смотрит в тип объекта.

Comment: Копать куда-то [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34145112/12888024). Вешать атрибут на свойство и в событии автогенерации `e.Cancel = true`, если надо пропустить колонку.

Comment: Господа, большое спасибо за советы, я вижу, что мой "физический смысл" задачи позволил найти оптимальный подход, а как альтернатива -  я еще и с меппером поигрался

Comment: В EntityFramework эта проблема решается "контейнерами", из-за сложности контейнеров - они бывают даже "анонимными". Но это не самое удобное решение, тем более, что контейнер предполагает наличие двух сущностей одновременно. Собственно контейнер и содержимое. Если вы свои сущности можете так разделить - то пишите контейнеры. Фабрики... не фабрики не подойдут. Интерфейсы - возможно подойдут. По контейнерам дать красивый ответ с примерами - у меня не получится.

Comment: @nick_n_a - спасибо, что указали мне на эту возможжность, теперь, если понадобится - я смогу сам нагуглить пример, ведь главное -знать, что искать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так делать нельзя, т.к. это нарушает принцип ООП, может привести к путанице с свойствами, а закрыть доступ не всегда увенчается успехом, я считаю что для вашего случая вам нужны **[атрибуты](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)**.

ООП предполагает что у вас есть свойства. Все доступные свойства для "внешнего" программиста (который не будет заглядывать в внутренности вашей либы) - должны быть в public. Все которые для "внутреннего" программиста (который будет наследовать ваш класс) - protected. Никому не доступны - private. Но, это модель доступности свойств для открытия закрытия общего програмного доступа к свойствам.

Если нужно, что бы часть часть доступных свойств отображалась в программах, библиотеках, т.е. для фильтрации свойств и методов програмно - истользуются атрибуты. В c# есть методы, позволяющие выбрать свойства/методы отмеченные конкретными атрибутами. Это позволяет добавлять/удалять свойства из визуальных редакторов, из списка сериализации и т п.

Из извесных атрибутов обратите внимание на (привожу для примера, желательно знать что такие есть) `System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute` (отображаемое имя), `System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute` (отображать/неотображать),
 `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` (не отображать свойство/метод в списке редакторе кода даже если оно там есть с меткой public), `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore` (для исключения из xml-сериализации). Так же вы можете создать свой атрибут и задействовать его.

Так же для разных технологий есть свои атрибуты, управляющие захватом свойств и методов. У EntitiFramework они свои, у ньютона они свои, если ваш принимает участие внутри определенной библиотеки-технологии - ознакомьтесь какие там бывают атрибуты - может оказаться что там уже есть признак "видимости".

Comment: `System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute` не работает в WPF, он аффектит только `DataGridView` в Winforms.

Comment: В разных библиотеках фильтрация по-разному устроена, где-то она есть, а где-то не предусмотрена вообще.

Comment: здесь речь конкретно про DevExpress

Comment: Вообще не понял причём тут: ни WPF, ни WinForms, ни DataGridView, ни DevExpress.